# OSX C++ Export function

Tags: c++, macos

I got a large C++ project that uses a makefile on OSX. where I simply want to add an exported function that I can resolve can call. The project needs to be an executeable and not a library. It already exports a bunch of functions but I cannot get my export to work, meaning it's not visible when I run nm on the binary.

I tried to simply add this to the header .h

```
#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
EXPORT int callme(int test);
```

I also tried declaring it in the header like

```
EXPORT int callme(int test) {return 0;}
```

but then i get a bunch of errors of the symbol already existing in other object files.

Edit: It's a simple C function and I also tried

```
 #if !defined(__cplusplus)
 #define MONExternC extern
 #else
 #define MONExternC extern "C"
 #endif

 MONExternC int callme (int test);
```

I'm a bit of novice when it comes to C++ and any insight or help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is this a C function you're exporting or a C++ one? You may need to wrap it in an [`extern "C" { ... }`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c) block. It might be exported correctly, but with a C++ function name.

Comment: It's a simple C function, i added context to the post of what i tried.

Answer (score 1):

You have *defined* (not just declared) a standalone, non-member, non-template, non-inline function in a header. This is exactly the thing you should not be doing. It leads to the sort of errors you describe, and is prohibited by the standard.

You should have only a function ptototype in the header. Move its definition to an exactly one source file.

The visibility attribute only makes sense when building shared libraries. You probably don't need it.